# The HTML is displayed with unrecognizable code when it's dispatchered by a servlet

Tags: html, servlets, utf-8, character-encoding

I write a login page, when you fail,the page will be dispatchered back with a tip by a servlet. When the HTML Code is "UTF-8", It's displayed with **unrecognizable code**. After I changed the code by "GB2312", It's normal. Why?

Comment: Can you an example? There a few reasons why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that you're seeing [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)? You need to ensure that you're using UTF-8 everywhere.

- Your editor must save JSP files as UTF-8. How to do it depends on the editor. In Eclipse for example, it's configureable by *Window > Preferences > Web > JSP files > Encoding*.
- Your JSP must set the response encoding to UTF-8. One of the ways is to put this in top of the JSP:

  ```
  <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
  ```

  This will also implicitly set the HTTP response `Content-Type` header with the UTF-8 charset so that the webbrowser understands what charset it has to use to present the page. This will also implicitly tell the browser what charset it has to use to send the submitted POST form data.
- Your server must interpret request URI as UTF-8 so that GET parameters are properly decoded. How to do it depends on the server. In case of for example Tomcat, it's a matter of adding `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to the `<Connector>` element in `/conf/server.xml`.

  ```
  <Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">
  ```
- Your webapp must interpret request body as UTF-8 so that POST parameters are properly decoded. A common practice is to do it in a `Filter`.

  ```
  if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
      request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  }

  chain.doFilter(request, response);
  ```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: +1; especially for mentioning Mojibake - was not aware of that term :-)

Comment: @home: there's even a tag for it: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mojibake/info